# Allow only http PUT requests with iptables

Tags: http, get, couchdb, iptables, put

I want to allow a connection from a specific interface (e.g eth2) to only make http PUT requests and not GET requests to my database.Is that possible using iptables?

Comment: Unlikely. iptables doesn't concern itself with the actual data passed through a socket.

Answer (score 1):

You may try...:

```
iptables -I INPUT -d 192.168.0.100 -p tcp --dport 5984 -m string --string 'GET /' --algo bm -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -d 192.168.0.100 -p tcp --dport 5984 -m string --string 'PUT /' --algo bm -j ACCEPT
```

...but on your own risk - iptables isn't best tool for HTTP filtering. Better setup real HTTP proxy, like Nginx, in front of CouchDB to have more flexible and optimal control over all HTTP requests that you receive.